# Finding line of sight on a hex grid using only coordinates

Tags: c#, hex, hexagonal-tiles

I have a flat top hex grid where each hex has coordinates `[x,y,z]` where the first element is the column increasing left to right, the second is the / diagonal increasing from left to right, and the third is the \ diagonal increasing from right to left. So for example the first column is `0,0,0 ; 0,1,1 ; 0,2,2 ; 0,3,3` etc. the next is `1,1,0 ; 1,2,1 ; 1,3,2` etc. and so on for the other columns.

My goal is to write a function (C#) that can find the coordinates of all the hexes that lie on a line between two end hexes, including any hexes that the line runs along the border of.

I have figured out how to do it by hand, but I'm having trouble translating it into code. Here is what I have using hexes `0,2,2` and `3,3,0`:

Find the greatest difference between corresponding x, y, or z coordinates. In this case it is 3. This means there are 4 hexes in the path and 3 'jumps' between hexes.
For each pair of x, y, and z coordinates, step from a to b distributing the steps symmetrically over the 'jumps'. In this example: `0>1>2>3, 2>2>3>3, 2>1>1>0`.
From this, the path is `0,2,2 ; 1,2,1 ; 2,3,1 ; 3,3,0`

If there is no symmetrical way to distribute the steps, use all the ways to distribute them as symmetrically as possible.
e.g. `0,2,2` to `2,3,1`  where the line passes exactly between two hexes
Biggest coordinate difference is 2 so there are 3 hexes involved (not really but for now just pretend).
For the x coordinates it is simple: `0>1>2`.
But y: `2>2>3` or `2>3>3`.
And z: `2>2>1` or `2>1>1`.

Taking all the possibilities, the middle hex could be `1,2,2 ; 1,2,1 ; 1,3,2` or `1,3,1`.
There are no hexes with coordinates `1,2,2` or `1,3,1` , so the line passes along the border of the other two.

I haven't tested this method super thoroughly but everything I have tested works.

I'm not necessarily asking for a direct translation into C#, but I genuinely have no idea how to proceed so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.